# Eclipse RCP, RMI and Bundles

Tags: eclipse-rcp, classloader, rmi, bundle

I'm trying to combine Eclipse RCP with RMI. For that purpose I created six bundles:
(In parenthesis are dependencies)

- Core: Interfaces for client and server
- Server(Core): Server implementation and Registry start class
- ServerApp(Server): GUI client which basically just instantiates the registry starter (and starts it on Activation)
- Client(Core): Client implementation
- ClientApp(Client): GUI client

Now I started the serverapp, but I got a

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: core.rmi.CallbackServerInterface (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

Now I started the server with

```
-consoleLog -Djava.security.policy=java.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${workspace_loc}/core/
```

(My java.policy file is in the core plugin).
I thought the problem was the classpath. So I made core and server buddies:

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered
```

in the core bundle manifest file and

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: core
```

In the server bundle manifest file. 
Which didn't help, since I got the exact same error.

Does anyone know where I could have gone wrong on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the problem was, that OSGI uses its own Classloader. So before we do the Naming bind we need:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
                    this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

After this, the server works like a charm, and the client can connect.