# RMI callbacks in Eclipse RCP

Tags: callback, eclipse-rcp, classloader, rmi

[image: Bundles]

So I'm using RMI in an Eclipse RCP application. The classloader of RMI and OSGI hate each other so much, but I could solve my first problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650619/eclipse-rcp-rmi-and-bundles).

My server application consists of the **Server** bundle, which depends on **Core**. Additionally the bundle **Map** is loaded, using an extension point of core (**DataUpdate**).

Similarly the **Client** is started depending on **Core** and loading **Map** as a plugin.

Now sending a **User** from the client to the **Server** poses no problem anymore (solved issue above). Sadly the reverse doesn't work. The **Client** is stored as Callback on the **Server** and should receive **DataUpdate** objects. Those are created in the **Map** bundle on the server and sent via RMI. When I receive them on the client side I get the ominous ClassNotFound exception. I do the same as on the server:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
                this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

But this doesn't help. Also to start both server and client my start parameters are:

```
-consoleLog -Djava.security.policy=java.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${workspace_loc}
```

And in the client I set the security manager to a personal implementation which allows everything.

So does anyone have an idea, why the class is not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the cynic answer to this is not to use the Sun RMI implementation.

I now use [Kryonet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) for which I can set the classes of the objects being sent over the Network. Since each of these classes knows its classloader the problem is solved.